# Can a non-EU citizen with an EU residence permit cross the border in the EU citizen channel?

Tags: borders, eu-citizens, residency

This is the question I am really eager to know. If I already have an EU residence permit from Poland, when I enter into the EU zone, can I line up in the same channel as EU citizens? Or is there any special channel for residence holders?